# How to ignore "-Wunused-result" and "-Wunused-but-set-variable" Errors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

recently I got some errors in Eclipse while upgrading to Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) from 3.6 (Helios),

My environment as following:

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04 32bit
- Eclipse: 4.2 Juno
- GCC: 4.6.3

my code as following:

```
static void doMatch(check_context_ptr ctxt)
{
    char    *cmd, *result;
    int k;//test 20120417
    char sourceName[10];
    asprintf(&cmd, "match %s %d %d\n",ctxt->filename, ctxt->probe_count, ctxt->threshold);
    free(cmd);
    for(k=0;k<10;k++)
        sourceName[k]=ctxt->filename[39+k];
}
```

the errors such as the followings:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

- warning: ignoring return value of 'asprintf', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
- warning: variable 「sourceName」 set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

I know there are all warnings, but in my eclipse they are showed in errors items

[image]

I know there are a solution to solve the error by line 60, 64 and 71, such as the following:
[image]

I know it is a bad programming style, but I always use this way to test my code, and I am sure the command parameters have a -wall option, and set unused return value flag as warning in code analysis setting.
so anybody know how to ignore the warning errors? How to set the parameter in Eclipse?

Comment: I solved it. 
I changed the eclipse all language related environment variable to en_US_UTF-8
Window -> Preference -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment -> LANGUAGE, LANG, LC_ALL, LC_MESSAGE, etc..

Answer (score 0):

In reference to [Strange diagnostic pragma behavior in GCC 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832687/strange-diagnostic-pragma-behavior-in-gcc-4-6), it's a localized question. so I just do change the language related environment variable to en_US_UTF-8. (Window -> Preference -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment)
the related environment variable:  LANGUAGE, LANG, LC_ALL, LC_MESSAGE, etc..